# Should the repository layer return data-transfer-objects (DTO)?

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, n-tier-architecture, dto, service-layer

I have a repository layer that is responsible for my data-access, which is called by a service layer. The service layer returns DTOs which are serialized and sent over the wire. More often than not, services do little more than access a repository and return whatever the repository returns.

But for that to work, the repository has to return an instance of that DTO. Otherwise, you would first have to map the data layer object that the repository returns to a DTO in the service layer and return that. That just seems wasteful.

On top of that, if creation of the DTOs happens in the service layer, something that might have been done before in one repository call and thus one database query, now has to happen with multiple repository calls in the service layer to 'compose' the final DTO. Unless of course I create a transport object for between the data and service layer that can contain such a composed object. Which *then* has to be mapped to a DTO. It just seems wasteful for the sake of purity. But it also feels wrong to have the repository layer return objects that just exist to be sent over the wire.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: repository is responsible for turning persisted data back to entities (models) and vice versa.

Model is a business Model representing a business entity. DTO on the other hand - while looks like Model - is concerned with transfer of the object between various environment and in essence is a transient object. Usually **mappers** are responsible for turning model into DTO.

Comment: Okay, so if I wanted to be pure I would have my repository return an entity (data model) which the service layer then maps to a DTO and sends it over the wire? What about the specialized transfer objects for between the service and data layer for more complex queries to avoid having to do multiple queries?

Comment: What if your persistence layer went from a DB to Web services?  So in this case you will no longer need the Data Entities (model) that EF has created. To persist data now, you will need to populate a WebService Request object and pass that to the service.  I think that EF entities and the WebServiceRequest/Response object should only be contained inside the Repos.  That being said it is fine to pass back a DTO (or Application Object) from the Repository. The EF entities or Request/Resonse object are only needed for your persistent layer.

Comment: @caa Did someone say the repo was returning EF Entities?

Comment: So your repository needs to hydrate the entire entity even if it's not being used? This seems very inefficient.

Comment: If Repository doesn't return DTO, how do I control Repository to do LEFT JOINs based my needs so I can shape the DTO I need? I have to call Repository many times to complete a single DTO in Application Service? Didn't this also introduce N+1 issue?

Answer (score 5):

> So your repository needs to hydrate the entire entity even if it's not being used? This seems very inefficient. – ajbeaven Oct 29 '18 at 23:25

Couldn't you add methods to the repository interface for calls that don't need to hydrate the entire entity?  I suppose that could lead to bloated interfaces, which is one of the main arguments against, I think.

To answer the question, I agree with the accepted answer of No.  Repository implementations are in the persistence layer. The domain layer may need to retrieve deep or shallow objects from the persistence layer which knows nothing except the Interface it must implement.  If the domain is constantly asking for a full refrigerator when it only needs butter, then maybe the Interface (or perhaps the data model) need some work.